# Ubuntu stuck after decrypt - Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found

Tags: lvm

During installation, I choose to encrypt the system. This was working fine for a couple of days, and suddenly I get this error message:

This erros are displayed after decription.

```
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume-group ubuntu-vg
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume-group ubuntu-vg
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found Volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
2 logical volume(s) in volume groupu "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 403387/31121408 files, 10066194/124455936 blocks
```

I have not made any configuration changes in the past few days, only using the computer for web browsing.

System is stuck. Kernel version 5.0.0-36(reinstall nothing change)

Comment: How did you encrypt your system? Add as much detail as possible about what you did, preferably including exact commands, config files edited and so forth.

Comment: @vidarlo - Standard, in Ubuntu Installation

Comment: So you installed your system, and during installation you enabled encryption? And the system was working for a while, and then stopped working?

Comment: After two days, yes, it's really wired because yesterday i was using pc only for facebook

Comment: I've edited your question to include the information given in comments :) In the future, it's always better to include as much information as possible from the start. You can always [edit] your question if you think there's more information that can be helpful, or I've misrepresented something from the comments.

Comment: @vidarlo thank u very much